# Accessing access token in cookies via XMLHttpRequest in Javascript

Tags: javascript, rest, http, authentication, get

I am a bit of a javascript newbie.

I am trying access a REST endpoint that requires authorization. I've authorized correctly. The documentation on this endpoint says

> "Successful authentication returns HTTP code 200, AccessToken cookie set to the proper value (if called from a browser the cookie will be automatically set so no extra work needed)"

So I authenticate, but then when i send a GET request to the URL I am getting a response saying that I am not authenticated. How do I access the token that's in the cookie so i can authenticate? thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

Comment: I would suggest sharing which API this is or more info from docs. Also, generally "cookie-based" and "token-based" API authentication are 2 different ways of doing authentication. I've never heard the term AccessToken Cookie, it's a bit muddy. 

(edit)
Having seen Phil's comment, it's likely the "withCredentials" is the problem if it's cookie based.

Comment: I have withCredentials set to true already.

Comment: Yes, definitely need more information then. Code examples or pseudo-code would help, as well as the info I mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: this is for an elastic search query here at work. 

the authentication code is
 var requestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var body = {"username":"MY_USERNAME","password":"MY_PASSWORD"}
    requestObject.open('POST', 'https://BASE.SEARCH.com/api/login', false);
    requestObject.send(JSON.stringify(body));

Comment: the query code is:
var queryObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requestObject.open('GET','https://BASE.SEARCH.com/api/search',false);
    requestObject.setRequestHeader('query','prompt');
    requestObject.withCredentials = 'true';
    requestObject.send();

 (the BASE and SEARCH part of the URL have been changed, of course)

Comment: Everyone, thanks for your help. After INSISTING that the person who wrote this endpoint go back and take another look, he conceded there was, indeed, a bug with how they were checking authentication. I appreciate the help! your answers helped me confirm that i was, indeed, on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

there was a bug in the code. The cookie should, indeed, be submitted when "withCredentials" is set to true on the XMLHttpRequest object.